# Firefox linebreak in code creates spacing between elements

Tags: css, firefox

In firefox, when code is formatted with linebreaks like so:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>bullet</li>
        <li>bullet</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>bullet</li>
        <li>bullet</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

There is space between these elements. To get rid of it I have to put the code on one line like so:

```
<div><ul><li>bullet</li><li>bullet</li></ul><ul><li>bullet</li><li>bullet</li></ul></div>
```

Is there a way of avoiding this with some CSS magic?

EDIT: I have a reset css:

```
*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section{display:block;}
body{line-height:1;}
ol, ul{list-style:none;}
blockquote, q{quotes:none;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after{content:'';content:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;}
```

using HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>`

Comment: with reset css? check this [demo](http://jsbin.com/UdOgekI/3/edit)

Comment: Not reproduceable on Firefox 24 with the code included in the question. You should describe specific immediately observable differences, instead of just saying “There is space between these elements” (which elements?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, my favorite way to do this:

ul {
font-size:0
}
ul li {
font-size: 10px
}

Here is more info: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Use this or don't put breaks between your elements like you have in your example.